# Rails: Active Storage not uploading files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, rails-activestorage

I'm trying to upload an image to my rails API using active storage and sending it as a FormData through my Vue Application. Image is not uploaded in localStorage, but API success. How to fix it?

**vue.js**

register() execute upload, then file upload in Rails

```
    <template>
    <v-app>
        <div class="editor">
            <input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" placeholder="Title" v-model="title">
        </div>
        <div class="relationImages">
            <label for="image">image: </label>
            <input type="file" id="image" name="image" accept="image/png,image/jpeg" @change="setImage" />
        </div>
        <div class="relationImages">
            <button class="registerButton" @click="register">Register</button>
        </div>
    </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            title: '',
            imageFile: null
        };
    },
    methods: {
        async register() {
            try {
                const formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('images', this.imageFile, this.imageFile.name);

                const data = {
                    title: this.title,
                    images: formData,
                }
                const res = await axios.post(import.meta.env.VITE_APP_API_BASE + '/goals', data)
                console.log(res);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log({ error })
            }
        },
        setImage(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.imageFile = e.target.files[0];
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

**Rails Controller**

```
class GoalsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @goal = Goal.create(goal_params)
        render json: { goal: @goal }, status: 200
    end

    def goal_params
        params.permit(:title, :images)
    end    
end
```

title registered, but image not uploaded(/storage path).

**Rails Model**

```
class Goal < ApplicationRecord
    has_many_attached :images
end
```

**development.rb**

```
config.active_storage.service = :local
```

**Gem**

`image_processing` removed comment out.

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby "3.1.0"

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem "rails", github: "rails/rails", branch: "main"
gem "rails", "~> 7.0.4", ">= 7.0.4.2"

# The original asset pipeline for Rails [https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails]
gem "sprockets-rails"

# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem "pg", "~> 1.1"

# Use the Puma web server [https://github.com/puma/puma]
gem "puma", "~> 5.0"

# Use JavaScript with ESM import maps [https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails]
gem "importmap-rails"

# Hotwire's SPA-like page accelerator [https://turbo.hotwired.dev]
gem "turbo-rails"

# Hotwire's modest JavaScript framework [https://stimulus.hotwired.dev]
gem "stimulus-rails"

# Build JSON APIs with ease [https://github.com/rails/jbuilder]
gem "jbuilder"

# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem "redis", "~> 4.0"

# Use Kredis to get higher-level data types in Redis [https://github.com/rails/kredis]
# gem "kredis"

# Use Active Model has_secure_password [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html#securepassword]
# gem "bcrypt", "~> 3.1.7"

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby ]

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem "bootsnap", require: false

gem 'rack-cors'

gem 'dotenv'

# Use Sass to process CSS
# gem "sassc-rails"

#Use Active Storage variants [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#transforming-images]
gem "image_processing", "~> 1.2"

group :development, :test do
  # See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-debug-gem
  gem "debug", platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ]
end

group :development do
  # Use console on exceptions pages [https://github.com/rails/web-console]
  gem "web-console"

  # Add speed badges [https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler]
  # gem "rack-mini-profiler"

  # Speed up commands on slow machines / big apps [https://github.com/rails/spring]
  # gem "spring"
end

group :test do
  # Use system testing [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#system-testing]
  gem "capybara"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
  gem "webdrivers"
end
```

Rails Log

```
Parameters: {"title"=>"aaa", "images"=>{}, "goal"=>{"title"=>"aaa"}}
Unpermitted parameters: :images, :goal. Context: { controller: GoalsController, action: create, request: #<ActionDispatch::Request:0x00007f0316d9eb88>, params: {"title"=>"aaa", "images"=>{}, "controller"=>"goals", "action"=>"create", "goal"=>{"title"=>"aaa"}} }
TRANSACTION (0.6ms)  BEGIN
↳ app/controllers/goals_controller.rb:5:in `create'
Goal Create (2.9ms)  INSERT INTO "goals" ("title", "description", "start_date", "end_date", "category_id", "create_user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"  [["title", "aaa"], ["description", nil], ["start_date", nil], ["end_date", nil], ["category_id", nil], ["create_user_id", nil], ["created_at", "2023-09-10 12:39:33.182906"], ["updated_at", "2023-09-10 12:39:33.182906"]]
↳ app/controllers/goals_controller.rb:5:in `create'
TRANSACTION (4.5ms)  COMMIT
↳ app/controllers/goals_controller.rb:5:in `create'
Completed 200 OK in 30ms (Views: 0.4ms | ActiveRecord: 8.0ms | Allocations: 2350)
```

I change register() in vue like below(add multipart/form-data), log changes `ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature`.

```
const res = await axios.post(import.meta.env.VITE_APP_API_BASE + '/goals', data, {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': '"multipart/form-data"'
                    }
                })
```

```
Parameters: {"title"=>"aaa", "images"=>"[object FormData]"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 751)
ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature (ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature):  
app/controllers/goals_controller.rb:5:in `create'
```

Comment: What logs do you have for this request?

Comment: Rails won't accept JSON for file uploads. You may need to set it up as a multipart/form request. Can you edit the question with the request/response logs you got from the Rails console?

Comment: I add rails log. In case of adding multipart/form, I add too.